# Stacked IF AND Statement returns #Value error

Tags: excel, if-statement

I'm probably doing this wrong.. it returns a #Value error...

=IF(AND(B2=0,W2<>0),1,0),IF(AND(B2>0,W2=0),1,0)

Comment: Try to be more specific  describe your case along with the issue you are facing

Comment: `=IF(AND(B2=0,W2<>0), 1, IF(AND(B2>0,W2=0), 1, 0))`

Comment: @Jeeped Please don't put answers in comments.

Comment: @ale10ander - this question should be closed as a typographical error. With that said, the OP still deserves an answer as we have all had 'can not see the forest for the trees' moments and the OP has supplied more pertinent information than 90% of other 'questions' asked lately.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is work with values. For instance, if the column with net amount has value, then the shipping column should have value, and if net amount is 0, then shipping amount should be 0.. true, false or 1,0

Comment: @Jeeped that's fine, vote to close the question, but provide your solution as an answer.

Comment: I put the answer, not sure if it posted.  This is what I got and it worked.  I actually just kept searching for something similar.. =IF(AND(B2=0,W2<>0),1,IF(AND(B2>0,W2=0),1,0))

Answer (score 4):

IF only allows 3 arguments and you can't just join them outside each other with a `,`.

```
=IF(OR(AND(B2=0,W2<>0),AND(B2>0,W2=0)),1,0)
```

Or if you only want `1` or `0` as the outputs then:

```
=--OR(AND(B2=0,W2<>0),AND(B2>0,W2=0))
```

The `--` will turn TRUE/FALSE to 1/0 respectively.

As per @Jeeped's comment.

Comment: `=--OR(AND(B2=0, W2<>0), AND(B2>0, W2=0))`

Comment: @Jeeped Please don't put answers in comments.

Comment: Thank you everyone.  I will work with the answers provided.  What I'm trying to do is work with values.  For instance, if the column with net amount has value, then the shipping column should have value, and if net amount is 0, then shipping amount should be 0.. true, false or 1,0